# Dynamically-created element overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamically-created list div made using  `document.createElement()`. The div is pulling elements from a database and displaying them. I noticed that when the list is long, the content is cut off despite having set  `overflow: auto` in the body. I subsequently tried adding a large div directly in the HTML and it successfully triggers the scroll bar's appearance--so clearly there's an issue with the dynamic aspect of the div. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add a max-width

```
.Body__container--categories {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 18%;
}
```